# How to pass a function into a data class in Kotlin?

Tags: function, kotlin

When I ran the following in the [kotlin playground](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Hello,%20world!/Simplest%20version/Simplest%20version.kt), it prints error, nothing else. What's wrong with the following code? It's pretty simple, I am passing in a function into the data class as one of it's initialization parameters, and then calling this function on the data class instance. Is it not allowed to pass function into a data class in Kotlin?

```
data class Person(val name: String,
                  val age: Int = 0,
                  val showMsg : (msg: String) -> Unit)


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val p = Person(name="Bob", age=29, {msg -> println(msg)})
    p.showMsg("Hello, world!")
}
```

Comment: It would be really cool if you'd share the link to **your** playground (use the save function)

Comment: What error do you get? The Kotlin playground currently gives me `Internal Server Error`.

Comment: It gave me "error: ", that's all, nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use named arguments for 2 of the parameters and ignore the last one (the lambda/function parameter), you just need to name the last parameter as follows.

```
val p = Person(name="Bob", age=29, showMsg = {msg -> println(msg)})
```

Comment: ha, that's was easy... was stuck on that for about 2 hours.

Comment: Use an IDE the next time ;)

Answer (score 8):

A viable alternative to the solutions in the other answers is to pass the last argument lambda outside the parentheses.

If a function takes another function as the last parameter, the lambda expression argument can be passed outside the parenthesized argument list. In this case, you don't need to use a named argument for it:

```
val p = Person(name = "Bob", age = 29) { println(it) }
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot mix named and positioned arguments. Use

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val p = Person(name="Bob", age=29, showMsg = {msg -> println(msg)})
    p.showMsg("Hello, world!")
}
```

or

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val p = Person("Bob", 29, {msg -> println(msg)})
    p.showMsg("Hello, world!")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked fine for me;

```
data class Person(val name: String,
                  val age: Int = 0,
                  val showMsg : (String) -> Unit
)

val p = Person(name="Bob", age=29, showMsg = ::println)
p.showMsg("Hello, world!")
```